# Setting URL's for cakephp facebook app for integrating localhost website with facebook login

Tags: php, plugins, facebook-apps, cakephp-2.1

I am using the webtechnich Facebook plugin to integrate the Facebook login with my cakephp website. I executing on the local host. Since I am executing on the local host **I am not able to give the correct site URLs , canvas URLs and App domain while creating the Facebook App in the Facebook Developers site.**

> My local host website login url-

```
http://localhost/fbtest/users/login
```

In Facebook developer App settings I have given-

```
1. Canvas URL - http://localhost/fbtest/
 2. Site URL- http://localhost/fbtest/
 3. App Domain- http://localhost
```

With this settings I am able to login but following is the error I am getting:

**Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.**

Answer (score 0):

use the url
http://apps.facebook.com/yourappname/
in place of the url asked by the application